# React Vite enviornment variables import.meta.env not found

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm working on a react application and I ported it over to use vite. VS Code is complaining about my .env environment variables now. In my app I have used `import.meta.env.VITE_VARIABLE` and VS Code underlines `env` in red. The code works and the variable is properly extracted, but the type contianing the `env` property is not recognized.  I have tried adding in the root folder a `vite-env.d.ts` typescript definition file to extend ImportMeta as below:

```
interface ImportMeta {
  env: Record<string, string>
}
```

This however does nothing.

How do I fix the typescript errors?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I needed to move the file into my src folder, I think because that is where tsConfig.json was looking.